# pre-commit giving error with mirrors-mypy, how do I fix it?

Tags: apple-m1, mypy, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

I am getting the below error when running "pre-commit run --all-files" and when trying to make a commit, it is some python error, python version in use is "Python 2.7.16".

```
[INFO] Installing environment for https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-mypy.
[INFO] Once installed this environment will be reused.
[INFO] This may take a few minutes...
An unexpected error has occurred: CalledProcessError: command: ('/Users/user/.cache/pre-commit/repoq_mv31g8/py_env-default/bin/python', '-mpip', 'install', '.', 'tokenize-rt==3.2.0', 'pydantic')
return code: 1
expected return code: 0
stdout:
    Processing /Users/user/.cache/pre-commit/repoq_mv31g8
      Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
      Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
    Collecting tokenize-rt==3.2.0
      Using cached tokenize_rt-3.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.1 kB)
    Collecting pydantic
      Using cached pydantic-1.9.0-cp310-cp310-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl (2.4 MB)
    Collecting mypy==0.782
      Using cached mypy-0.782-py3-none-any.whl (2.4 MB)
    Collecting mypy-extensions<0.5.0,>=0.4.3
      Using cached mypy_extensions-0.4.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.5 kB)
    Collecting typing-extensions>=3.7.4
      Using cached typing_extensions-4.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
    Collecting typed-ast<1.5.0,>=1.4.0
      Using cached typed_ast-1.4.3.tar.gz (210 kB)
      Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
      Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
    Building wheels for collected packages: pre-commit-dummy-package, typed-ast
      Building wheel for pre-commit-dummy-package (setup.py): started
      Building wheel for pre-commit-dummy-package (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
      Created wheel for pre-commit-dummy-package: filename=pre_commit_dummy_package-0.0.0-py3-none-any.whl size=1154 sha256=ea7d756fd19dee0f5f03851e3e343db4194f4b306f21fecb796b4d6d89d266fb
      Stored in directory: /private/var/folders/v4/nlc505k12rn9pf4c9kntz8qm0000gn/T/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-4jcph5rz/wheels/80/78/0d/746d1697141e342b257e21c980fc51ac134e6b6400568c3646
      Building wheel for typed-ast (setup.py): started
      Building wheel for typed-ast (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
      Running setup.py clean for typed-ast
    Successfully built pre-commit-dummy-package
    Failed to build typed-ast
    Installing collected packages: typed-ast, mypy-extensions, typing-extensions, tokenize-rt, pydantic, mypy, pre-commit-dummy-package
      Running setup.py install for typed-ast: started
      Running setup.py install for typed-ast: finished with status 'error'
    
stderr:
      error: subprocess-exited-with-error
      
      × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
      │ exit code: 1
      ╰─> [22 lines of output]
          running bdist_wheel
          running build
          running build_py
          package init file 'ast3/tests/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
          running build_ext
          building '_ast27' extension
          building '_ast3' extension
          ast3/Python/ast.c:844:5: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
              abort();
              ^~~~~
          ast3/Python/ast.c:4514:9: error: implicit declaration of function '_PyUnicode_DecodeUnicodeEscape' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
              v = _PyUnicode_DecodeUnicodeEscape(s, len, NULL, &first_invalid_escape);
                  ^
          ast3/Python/ast.c:4514:9: note: did you mean 'PyUnicode_DecodeUnicodeEscape'?
          /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/include/python3.10/unicodeobject.h:608:23: note: 'PyUnicode_DecodeUnicodeEscape' declared here
          PyAPI_FUNC(PyObject*) PyUnicode_DecodeUnicodeEscape(
                                ^
          ast3/Python/ast.c:4514:7: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'PyObject *' (aka 'struct _object *') from 'int' [-Wint-conversion]
              v = _PyUnicode_DecodeUnicodeEscape(s, len, NULL, &first_invalid_escape);
                ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
          2 warnings and 1 error generated.
          error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
          [end of output]
      
      note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      ERROR: Failed building wheel for typed-ast
      error: subprocess-exited-with-error
      
      × Running setup.py install for typed-ast did not run successfully.
      │ exit code: 1
      ╰─> [24 lines of output]
          running install
          /Users/user/.cache/pre-commit/repoq_mv31g8/py_env-default/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
            warnings.warn(
          running build
          running build_py
          package init file 'ast3/tests/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
          running build_ext
          building '_ast27' extension
          building '_ast3' extension
          ast3/Python/ast.c:844:5: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
              abort();
              ^~~~~
          ast3/Python/ast.c:4514:9: error: implicit declaration of function '_PyUnicode_DecodeUnicodeEscape' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
              v = _PyUnicode_DecodeUnicodeEscape(s, len, NULL, &first_invalid_escape);
                  ^
          ast3/Python/ast.c:4514:9: note: did you mean 'PyUnicode_DecodeUnicodeEscape'?
          /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/include/python3.10/unicodeobject.h:608:23: note: 'PyUnicode_DecodeUnicodeEscape' declared here
          PyAPI_FUNC(PyObject*) PyUnicode_DecodeUnicodeEscape(
                                ^
          ast3/Python/ast.c:4514:7: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'PyObject *' (aka 'struct _object *') from 'int' [-Wint-conversion]
              v = _PyUnicode_DecodeUnicodeEscape(s, len, NULL, &first_invalid_escape);
                ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
          2 warnings and 1 error generated.
          error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
          [end of output]
      
      note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
    error: legacy-install-failure
    
    × Encountered error while trying to install package.
    ╰─> typed-ast
    
    note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
    hint: See above for output from the failure.
    
Check the log at /Users/user/.cache/pre-commit/pre-commit.log
```

I am running it on Apple M1 Air (macOS Big Sur), what am I missing or is it a known M1 issue ?
I have tried installing pydantic manually, pre-commit is installed by brew.
Thanks in Advance

pre-commit config:

```
repos:
-   repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks
    rev: v4.0.1
    hooks:
    -   id: trailing-whitespace
    -   id: end-of-file-fixer
    -   id: check-yaml
    -   id: check-added-large-files

-   repo: https://github.com/psf/black
    rev: 21.7b0
    hooks:
    -   id: black

-   repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-mypy
    rev: v0.782
    hooks:
    -   id: mypy
        additional_dependencies: [pydantic]
```

Comment: please show your configuration, without that we cannot help.  it does seem odd that you're installing `tokenize-rt` (a library I made) especially given it does not provide types.  I suspect you're attempting to install a version of mypy which does not support M1

Answer (score 18, accepted):

you're installing a very old version of mypy (0.782) which depends on an old version of `typed-ast` (`<1.5.0`) which does not support M1

you can ~usually get to the latest version by running `pre-commit autoupdate` -- or pick a version newer than `0.900` (where mypy started support for M1)

---

disclaimer: I created `pre-commit`

Comment: Thanks creator of pre-commit, that worked like a charm

Answer (score 1):

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.

In short, when I try git commit, it will report an error because I have installed `pre-commit`:

```
An unexpected error has occurred: CalledProcessError: command: ('python', '-mpip', 'install', '.')
return code: 1
expected return code: 0
stdout:
    Executable `python` not found
```

First, we usually have `python3` installed, so the `python` command is invalid.

Do it:

```
sudo apt install python-is-python3
```

Then, you usually encounter this problem in Ubuntu 22.04:

```
An unexpected error has occurred: AssertionError: BUG: expected environment for python to be healthy immediately after install, please open an issue describing your environment

more info:

virtualenv python version did not match created version:
- actual version: <<error retrieving version from /home/wind/.cache/pre-commit/reposyb8net0/py_env-python3/bin/python>>
- expected version: 3.10.4.final.0
```

To fix this, add this line to your `.bashrc` file:

```
export SETUPTOOLS_USE_DISTUTILS=stdlib
```

Refresh the configuration file by restarting a terminal window or running `source ~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Thanks! For me it was just the SETUPTOOLS_USE_DISTUTILS that fixed it for me.