# How to solve pre-commit asserttion error on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: pre-commit, python-3.10, pre-commit.com, ubuntu-22.04

I am using ubuntu 22.04 and the python version is 3.10.4.
I have installed a Django project with the cookie-cutter. and now I have got an error when I want to commit my changes.

here is the error:

```
(blog) ➜  blog git:(main) ✗ pre-commit run
[INFO] Installing environment for https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks.
[INFO] Once installed this environment will be reused.
[INFO] This may take a few minutes...
An unexpected error has occurred: AssertionError: BUG: expected environment for python to be healthy() immediately after install, please open an issue describing your environment
Check the log at /home/mahdi/.cache/pre-commit/pre-commit.log
```

Content of pre-commit.log:

````
### version information

```
pre-commit version: 2.18.1
git --version: git version 2.34.1
sys.version:
    3.10.4 (main, Apr  2 2022, 09:04:19) [GCC 11.2.0]
sys.executable: /home/mahdi/.local/share/virtualenvs/blog-qatotdDy/bin/python
os.name: posix
sys.platform: linux
```

### error information

```
An unexpected error has occurred: AssertionError: BUG: expected environment for python to be healthy() immediately after install, please open an issue describing your environment
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mahdi/.local/share/virtualenvs/blog-qatotdDy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pre_commit/error_handler.py", line 73, in error_handler
    yield
  File "/home/mahdi/.local/share/virtualenvs/blog-qatotdDy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pre_commit/main.py", line 371, in main
    return run(args.config, store, args)
  File "/home/mahdi/.local/share/virtualenvs/blog-qatotdDy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pre_commit/commands/run.py", line 414, in run
    install_hook_envs(to_install, store)
  File "/home/mahdi/.local/share/virtualenvs/blog-qatotdDy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pre_commit/repository.py", line 221, in install_hook_envs
    _hook_install(hook)
  File "/home/mahdi/.local/share/virtualenvs/blog-qatotdDy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pre_commit/repository.py", line 83, in _hook_install
    raise AssertionError(
AssertionError: BUG: expected environment for python to be healthy() immediately after install, please open an issue describing your environment
```
````

I have search on google, but couldn't find any solution.

Comment: This isn't a Git issue and maybe isn't appropriate on StackOverflow. Instead, you should probably bring it up on [the pre-commit.com GItHub issues page](https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit/issues/) as an issue there. (Meanwhile I updated your tags to the one tag that *is* correct here.)

Comment: The instructions from the error message are pretty straight forward: "BUG: expected environment for python to be healthy() immediately after install, _please open an issue describing your environment_"

Comment: I will open an issue on github.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem but on Mac

```
An unexpected error has occurred: AssertionError: BUG: expected environment for python to be healthy immediately after install, please open an issue describing your environment

more info:

virtualenv python version did not match created version:
- actual version: <<error retrieving version from /Users/federico/.cache/pre-commit/repo9xb3zg69/py_env-python3.11/bin/python>>
- expected version: 3.11.2.final.0

Check the log at /Users/federico/.cache/pre-commit/pre-commit.log
```

Following [this thread](https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit/issues/2409#issuecomment-1274857735) I did

```
virtualenv --reset-app-data venv
```

And that resolved my problem

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue with python 3.10 on Ubuntu 22.04, you can use the python 3.10 from deadsnakes as directed [here](https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit/issues/2336#issuecomment-1097442008)

Side note, I also see that you opened a new ticket rather than searching the issue tracker within pre-commit, this issue was specifically called out in a number of tickets by searching "[healthy()](https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit/issues?q=is%3Aissue+healthy%28%29)". It would be preferable in the future to put some better search terms in place prior to logging an issue in GitHub to reduce the noise for open source maintainers.

Comment: I strongly dislike the solution of using deadsnakes, and the general attitude of the pre-commit "community".  This has been an issue for me for the last several hours, and windows its broken for a different reason, and no I am not going to install deadsnakes on 22.04

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with the following (you can add it to your `.bashrc`):

```
export SETUPTOOLS_USE_DISTUTILS=stdlib
```

thanks to this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73698579/4293684).